# TitleView is either not working or not centering

Tags: swift

i have a titleView containing a label and a (image-)button. I want the whole thing to be centered in the navigationbar(the of the whole bar not of the space between the left and right buttons). This seemed to be no problem, but the button didn't work. After doing some research i ended up adding

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize
}
```

with that my button works, but the view is no longer centered on the whole bar. Can anyone help me to achieve both?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], so we better understand the problem?

Comment: Please include relevant code.

Comment: The question is not clear, please write it clearly with some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a centering to any View, including a Layout, by using the XML attribute android:layout_gravity". You probably want to give it the value "center".

You can find a reference of possible values for this option here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity